# MySQL 5.1.7 conditional join of two tables selecting top record by date from second table and all records from first

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

- `instructions` — one unique record for each person
- `events` — multiple records for each person; records are of various types

I need to retrieve the compete list of instructions and, for each one, the `'appointment'` event with the greatest (latest) date.

I've experimented with `group by`, but haven't managed to get the right results.

The `instructions` table:

```
    id    first_name    surname    telephone
   ----  ------------  ---------  -----------
    1     bob           marley     555-1234
    2     steve         pike       555-3456
    3     daniel        osborne    555-9876
    4     mark          hodge      555-6600
    5     stefan        belfant    555-8080
```

The `events` table:

```
    id    instruction_id    type        commment    event_date
   ----- ----------------  ------------ ---------  ------------
    1     1                 create      na          2013-11-18
    2     2                 call        na          2013-11-19
    3     2                 appointment onsite      2013-12-02
    4     3                 create      na          2013-09-17
    5     3                 appointment office      2013-09-17
    6     3                 finalize    as discuss  2013-11-19
    7     4                 create      na          2013-12-02
    8     4                 cancel      na          2013-12-02
    9     5                 create      na          2013-10-02 
    10    1                 appointment at home     2013-11-22 
    11    2                 appointment at home     2013-12-05
```

The desired output:

```
    id   first_name     surname     telephone   appointment   comment
   ---- ------------   ---------   ----------- ------------- ---------
    1    bob            marley      555-1234    2013-11-22    at home  
    2    steve          pike        555-3456    2013-12-05    at home
    3    daniel         osborne     555-9876    2013-09-17    office
    4    mark           hodge       555-6600
    5    stefan         belfant     555-6060
```

Comment: Where are the queries you've attempted?

Comment: Hi Kermit; sorry im trying to format the tables so they look pretty. Not having much success.  I'll add my queries in 1 minute

Comment: thank you ruakh for helping with the edits and keeping it concise.

SQL:

SELECT instructions.id, instructions.first_name, instructions.surname, , appointments.status, appointments.status_date FROM instructions LEFT JOIN ( SELECT s1.* FROM instruction_status as s1 LEFT JOIN instruction_status AS s2 ON s1.instruction_id = s2.instruction_id AND s1.status_date < s2.status_date WHERE s2.status = 'Appointment' ) as appointments ON (instructions.id = appointments.instruction_id) limit 0,10;

Comment: thanks Ruakh;   I'm getting the following error having copied and pasted the SQL directly;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'latest_event_dates.event_date' in 'on clause'
mysql>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the latest/greatest appointment-date for any given person is unique, you can write:

```
SELECT instructions.*,
       latest_events.event_date AS appointment,
       latest_events.comment
  FROM instructions
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN ( SELECT events.instruction_id,
                MAX(events.event_date) AS latest_event_date
           FROM events
          WHERE events.type = 'appointment'
          GROUP
             BY events.instruction_id
       ) latest_event_dates
    ON instructions.id = latest_event_dates.instruction_id
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN events latest_events
    ON latest_event_dates.instruction_id = latest_events.instruction_id
   AND latest_event_dates.latest_event_date = latest_events.event_date
   AND 'appointment' = latest_events.type
;
```

(If the latest/greatest appointment-date is *not* unique, then you'll need to add another step in the join where you select the `MIN(events.id)` or `MAX(events.id)` or whatnot for a given `events.instruction_id` and `events.event_date`.)

Comment: I had edited the comment to say that the appointment date is not unique.  THere can be several appointments set.  We need the most recent appointment date in the result.

Comment: @StephenGrant: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but . . . this query doesn't require the appointment-date to be unique, as long as the *latest* appointment-date be unique. I mean -- it's O.K. if there are many appointments with the same instruction-ID, as long as there is a unique *latest* appointment with that instruction-ID. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes I think I see what you're saying; while there may be (and is) several appointment dates (actually timestamps) they are unique. There will not be duplicate identical appointments.  In spirit we need to know what the next appointment dates are.

Comment: @StephenGrant: Cool. Then this query should do what you want.

Comment: Hi ruakh; i've tried to make your query work but i keep getting errors.  i've amended a previous suggestion to include the exact table create and inserts

Comment: just a quick oberservation and comment; I've run this on a UAT database that has 82294 instructions and a  767287 entries in events.  I would expect from the limited test on the sample DB that I gave above, that I would have 82294 records returned. One for each instruction.  But I retrieved 118753.  Could this be related to your statement above "(If the latest/greatest appointment-date is not unique, then you'll need to add another step in the join where you select the MIN(events.id) or MAX(events.id) or whatnot for a given events.instruction_id and events.event_date.)

Comment: @StephenGrant: Yes, quite possibly.

Comment: OK, added in but im really lost.  This is so close i can almost taste it.  Did you mean to add as follows:
SELECT instruction_status.instruction_id, MAX(instruction_status.id),

Comment: Ruakh and Sadikhasan; both solutions are very close but still not the required outcome.  Sadikhasan your solution does work precisely; however the select * within the select * across 270,000 records is taking over 30 minutes to perform before I cancelled it.

Ruakh; yours works with the exception of returning duplicate records if the events table has more than one entry for appointment on the same day (which it does so we require the top most appointment)

Comment: @StephenGrant: How do you know which one is the "top most appointment", if they're both on the same day?

Comment: They are timestamps, however sometimes the user enters the appointment twice. Actually it happens often.

Comment: @StephenGrant: So if two appointments have the same instruction-ID and event-date, you don't care which one of them is returned?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT I.id,
       I.first_name,
       I.surname,
       I.telephone,
       E.event_date,
       E.comment
FROM instructions I
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT *
      FROM EVENTS
      WHERE EVENTS.type='appointment'
      ORDER BY EVENTS.event_date DESC) EVENTS
   GROUP BY EVENTS.type,
            EVENTS.instruction_id ) E ON I.id=E.instruction_id
```

Check [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25795a/90/0)

Comment: results: 
    +----+------------+---------+-----------+------------+---------+
    | id | first_name | surname | telephone | event_date | comment |

    +----+------------+---------+-----------+------------+---------+

    |  3 | Stefan     | Mazy    | 123456    | 2013-12-02 | onsite  |

    |  1 | Steve      | Grant   | 1234      | 2013-11-22 | at home |

    +----+------------+---------+-----------+------------+---------+

    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

it's missing the other entries from instructions.

Comment: Remove GROUP BY clause

Comment: your example doesn't have a group by clause; the statement from ruakh does but removing the group by still doesn't work

Comment: nope sorry.  Results now include multiple duplicates for instructions table:+----+------------+---------+-----------+------------+-------------+| id | first_name | surname | telephone | event_date | type        | comment |
|  1 | Steve      | Grant   | 1234      | 2013-12-05 | appointment | at home |
|  3 | Stefan     | Mazy    | 123456    | 2013-12-02 | appointment | onsite  |
|  1 | Steve      | Grant   | 1234      | 2013-11-22 | appointment | at home |

Comment: thanks again for your help Sadikhasan;  now the results are only two records.  The two with appointments and the most recent in each so that part is perfect;  but now I require the remaining other records from instructions.  This is exactly where I fell down trying to do this.  So I need to retrieve all instructions joined with the found set of appointments you just created

Comment: Can you send sql fiddle?

Comment: had amended to include SQL; i assume you removed that with your edit.  The query you gave still returns only the records from the events table with appointments.  As you can see from the above example, we need the entire instructions table joined with the results of your query.

Comment: Hi Sadikhasan :)  Well, that's very close, but it now leaves the issue of the proper record from events.  In your sql fiddle example, changing the DESC/ASC makes no difference. We require the top event being returned.  Have a look at this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89ae9/2

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution came from one of the staff working for me.... It's lightening quick and exactly what is required:

SELECT i.id, ins.type, ins.event_date
FROM instructions i
     left join instructions i
     on ins.id = (select inss.id
          FROM events inss
          WHERE inss.instruction_id = i.id AND inss.type = 'Appointment'
          ORDER BY inss.event_date DESC
          LIMIT 1
       );

The Group By method, no matter how I chose to do it, always returned odd results;

thank you everyone for your help on this, greatly appreciated.